# Optimal Dimensions for a Checkerboard-style board?

Tags: chess, checkers, board-size

Let me clarify.

First off: I have a sheet of paper, 8 1/2" by 8 1/2". What are the optimal dimensions (*<# of squares> by <# of squares>*) of a checkerboard-patterned board that I could print on this sheet of paper?

Second: I'm creating a board in an image editor. The squares can be any dimensions (*<# of pixels> by <# of pixels>*). What are the optimal dimensions of the squares themselves, and what is the optimal dimensions of the board (*<# of squares> by <# of squares>*)

By optimal, I mean the most amount of squares that still looks aesthetically pleasing.

**Also, I am open to different suggestions on what kind of "tiles" to use (i.e. squares or octagons or etc) and to what the dimensions are and sizes are. I merely chose checkerboard-style (square tiles) due to its ease of creation.**

Comment: Are you also using checkerboard style pieces?

Comment: @freekvd I'm not entirely sure what kind of pieces I'll be using at the moment; assume the pieces are circular and lack any sort of detailed markings, so they can be any size in reference to the checkerboard-style squares.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 'optimal' is easy to answer without getting into personal preference. There are certainly minimal and maximal sizes. A good example of a very small grid would be Halma (or Go). A good example of a large grid would be human chess. As long as you can make out the pieces and see the whole board. So it depends on the size, complexity, variation and even degrees of freedom in movement of your pieces.

Also squares might not be your best option. Go uses rectangles, so that when you view the board at a normal playing angle it looks like a square grid.

Comment: The reason why I'm using squares for the board is because I'm not using a static board - each board is created from a valid combination of four sub-boards, which can be arranged horizontally, vertically, or in a square. Also, I'm open to other suggestions for board-creation; I merely used square tiles because of the ease of making a checkerboard-style pattern.